# Concatinate output in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

I would like to output the result of the following plpgsql function in a concatenated text output.

How shall I go about it? I would like to have something like:

```
output = output + 'new point';
```

My function so far:

```
DECLARE 
    descriptions text[];
    i text;
    counter int := 1;
    _r record;
    output text;

BEGIN

    descriptions = string_to_array(description, ',');

    FOREACH i IN ARRAY descriptions

    LOOP

        FOR _r IN EXECUTE 'select point_id as id, name_of_location as name, description as desc
                   from information_on_point_of_interest
                   where description = '''||descriptions[counter]||''''

        LOOP
            output := output + _r.id || ',' || _r.name || ',' || _r.desc || '|';

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

RETURN output;

END;
```

`output := output + new point` does not seem to be supported?

Comment: The concat operator is `||` and you are using it in there except you suddenly decided to use `+` once. Why?

Comment: I have tried it but for some reason the output was a row with no values. Could it be there is a limit on the output length?

Comment: The function header is missing (`CREATE FUNCTION ... `). **Always** include the header, it is an integral part of the function. Just because some half-wit middleware truncates it, doesn't make it any less essential.

Comment: @IT_info it's not no value, it's `NULL`. The thing you posted shouldn't work at all so you should have posted that version. Most people, just like me, only look at the code till they found the first bug.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why?

Your function fails, because you don't initialize `output`. It starts as `NULL` stays `NULL` because `NULL || anything` results in .. `NULL`.

You should also use `concat_ws()` to take car of any `NULL` values in the concatenated  columns.

#### Proper solution

What you are trying to achieve can be done much faster (and correct) with this simple SQL query:

```
SELECT string_agg(concat_ws(',', point_id, name_of_location, description), '|')
FROM  (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(description_list, ',')) AS description) x
JOIN   information_on_point_of_interest USING (description);
```

I renamed your list of descriptions to `description_list` to make it less confusing.
Read about these functions in the manual:

- [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) (PostgreSQL 8.4+)
- [aggregate function `string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) (PostgreSQL 9.0+)
- [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) (PostgreSQL 9.1+)

Answer (score 1):

The concat operator is `||` which is the SQL standard.

Your problem is that didn't initialize that variable so what you're doing is `null || text` and the result of concatanating null with anything is null. You have to initialize it like this:

```
DECLARE 
    output text:='';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9e854/1